# Formatting inputs for LSTM layer with variable timestep using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

According to documentation, the LSTM layer should handle inputs with (None, CONST, CONST) shape. For **variable timestep**, it should be able to handle inputs with **(None, None, CONST) shape**.

Let say my data is the following :

```
X = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ],
    [
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]
]
Y = [0, 1]
```

And my model :

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation='tanh',input_shape=(None, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y)
```

My question is: **how should I format these inputs** to make this code work ?

I cannot use pandas dataframes here, as I was used to. If I run the code above, I get this error :

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:
```

And if I change the last line with :

```
model.fit(np.array(X), np.array(Y))
```

The error is now :

```
Error when checking input: expected lstm_8_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close but in Keras / Tensorflow you need to **pad** your sequences and then use a [Masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/) to let the LSTM skip those padded ones. *Why?* Because your entries in your tensor need to have the same shape `(batch_size, max_length, features)`. So if you have variable length, the sequence gets padded.

You can use [keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/) to pad your sequences to obtain something like:

```
X = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ],
    [
        [7, 8, 9],
        [0, 0, 0],
    ]
]
X.shape == (2, 2, 3)
Y = [0, 1]
Y.shape == (2, 1)
```

And then use the masking layer:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Masking(), # this tells LSTM to skip certain timesteps
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation='tanh',input_shape=(None, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, Y)
```

You also want `binary_crossentropy` since you have a binary classification problem with `sigmoid` output.